# css background image error...A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&)

Tags: css, asp.net

i'm developing a website in asp.net and i'm having difficulty getting an image to appear in the background the path of the image is correct as i've tested it. the error i am getting is:

> A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&).
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&).
>
> Source Error:
>   An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>   [HttpException (0x80004005): A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&).]
>     System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig() +9561124
>     System.Web.ValidateRequestExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +35
>     System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: Normally you get this error when it thinks it's a XSS attack or if particular characters are being used in the URL.  What's URL are you trying to request?

Comment: this is the url Nick "file://c:\users\lorna\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\JandD\JandD\css\images\photo 1.JPG")

Comment: Why not just do `background:url(images/my-image-name-here.jpg)` ..."

Comment: I've tried that but no luck

Comment: So you've got an `images` folder inside the `css` folder? And the `css` folder contains the `.css` files and an `images` folder? Is this correct?

Comment: yes thats correct Nick

Comment: OK - I think the problem is because the image name has a space in it, so when setting the background image, you should put either double or single quotes around the image name, `url("images/my-image-name-here.jpg")`

Comment: Just tried it there still no joy. Tried both double and single also tried renaming the image.